# how to generate a num in range

Tags: algorithm

I have a formula to generate a score, for example, score = UnixTimeOfNow(), but I want to get the final score in range of (1,n), such as (1,100). so how can I map the score to specific range?

Comment: Do you have any constraints on *how* score should be mapped to that range? (I presume always returning 1 will not be acceptable :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To map `score` to a value in range `(1, n)` inclusive you can do

```
score = 1 + (score % n);
```

(That's Java, C/C++ syntax.)

The `%` is the modulo operator which says that for instance `205 % 100` is `5`.

Comment: but if score1 = 106,score2 = 300, after your map, score1 is 7 > score2=1

Comment: Aha. You're probably just after score = (score / topScore) * n